# SQS - Schedule a message to de delivered

Tags: amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-sqs

I would like to publish a message on SQS and process that message after a few hours.

How can i schedule a message delivery or select messages from SQS based on some attribute?

I've implemented a SQS consumer but I'm receiving every message from SQS queue. Is possible to implement something like that on SQS? I was thinking about to receive every message and send to queue again if it's not time to process that message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a feature called as [Delay Queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html) in SQS, wherein if you set the delay on the queue then any message that is put on queue is available to consumers only after the delay duration has elapsed. However, the maximum delay that you can set there is 15 minutes and if you are looking for a delay of few hours this may not directly work for you.

The other option is to set a visibilty timeout for the messages higher than the delay time that you want. Then when you read the message you can get the message timestamp. If there is still some time left for your delay then you can sleep your consumer for the remaining time and after it has woken up you can process that message. However this is not a recommended way and would be highly inefficient because your threads are getting blocked. In fact what can as well be done is if there is still some time left for your delay then you just hold the message in a local List/Array and check for other messages and process this message after your delay. But all this would require entire logic to reside in your code and you don't get any ready-made feature from AWS